# Solve polynomial equation with negative power or non-integer power with python

Tags: python, math, sympy

I tried to solve the equation

```
1600 = 0.41 + 6.31*d**-1.54 + 2.42*d**-3
```

Mathematica can give me `d=6.4673` in less than 1 second. But I could not get the answer with python symbolic calculation.

Using "solve" of sympy take forever. Is there any way to solve this equation by using python symbolic calculation? It seems that the issues comes mainly from the non-integer negative power.

Comment: Perhaps if you include your Python code someone will be able to suggest an improvement.

Comment: Do your really need to solve it with symbolic calculation ? If you just want four digit of precision numpy can be used to solve it numerically.

Comment: What do you mean by Python Symbolic calculation? You can use scipy.optimize.fsolve to find the roots...

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.roots.html

Comment: @Namyts sympy is a symbolic calculation module wich would give exact solutions like mathematica or other CAS software. But indeed here the need is unclear.

Comment: @WIP I see. Yul, would it be possible to find the most negative power, and divide both sides of the equation by d^(-3) before using sympy's solve?

Comment: @Yul could you add some brackets to your equation to make it more clear

Comment: I know that as WIP said, the use of the numerical calculation with numpy make sense. I was curious to compare the capability of symbolic calculation between Mathematica and Python. As I said, Mathematica gave me the right answer very quickly. BTW, I tried to solve this equation with fsolve but it could not. It says that fsolve requires the positive power.

Comment: I think that Mathematica silently failed : here is what python say
    >>> d = 6.4673
    >>> 0.41 + 6.31*d**-1.54 + 2.42*d**-3
    0.7750004079825832
    >>> d = 0.1191
    >>> 0.41 + 6.31*d**-1.54 + 2.42*d**-3
    1600.0192723624311

Answer (score 2):

The first question to ask is: do you want a symbolic solution or a numeric solution.

For a **symbolic** solution: there isn't one. After the substitution `x = d**(-1/50)` the equation becomes `A*x**150 + B*x**77 + C == 0`. There is no symbolic formula for solving such high-degree polynomial equations.

For a **numeric** solution: you don't need SymPy, because SymPy is for symbolic computations. Find a root with SciPy. As a starting point:

```
from scipy.optimize import root
root(lambda d: 0.41 + 6.31*d**(-1.54) + 2.42*d**(-3) - 1600, 0.1)
```

This gives `0.1191005` as a solution. The initial point needs to be a small positive number, otherwise the solver will fail to converge. As WIP said, Mathematica failed in this way, and its answer is bogus.

But it's better to use a specialized solver for scalar equations, such as [`brentq`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brentq.html), especially because you have a monotone function here. This solver requires a bracketing interval to start with: one point where the function is positive, and another where it is negative. Without a calculator, one can notice that 0.1 gives a positive value (one of the terms is `2.42*1000`) while 1 gives a negative one (three small numbers minus 1600). So,

```
from scipy.optimize import brentq
brentq(lambda d: 0.41 + 6.31*d**(-1.54) + 2.42*d**(-3) - 1600, 0.1, 1)
```

which quickly and reliably returns with `0.11910050394499523`.

Answer (score 1):

SymPy provides numerical calculations via the `mpmath` library; this includes numerical root finding via `nsolve`. In this case, since there is a `d` in the denomominator, we do as the docstring of `nsolve` suggests and work with the numerator of the expression and give an initial guess. The same root that has already been cited is quickly found:

```
>>> f
-6.31*d**(-1.54) + 1599.59 - 2.42/d**3
>>> nsolve(f.as_numer_denom()[0], 1)
0.119100503944930
```